# Rotating the panel without rotating the controls

Tags: animation, customization

In rotating an animate panel is there a way to keep the control buttons where they so that they don't rotate? Or are there separate settings for the placement of control buttons?

```
Rotate[Animate[
  ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[n, {{1}, 0}, {40, All}]], {n, 0, 255, 
   1}, AnimationRunning -> False], 180 Degree]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotate `ArrayPlot` instead of `Animate`:

```
Animate[Rotate[#, 180 Degree] & @
   ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[n, {{1}, 0}, {40, All}]], 
 {{n, 89}, 0, 255, 1}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

or use the option `DataReversed -> {True, True}` in `ArrayPlot`:

```
Animate[ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[n, {{1}, 0}, {40, All}], 
  DataReversed -> {True, True}], 
 {{n, 89}, 0, 255, 1}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

to get

[image]